# unable to get proper textfield with tag while looping through uitextfield class in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, xcode9.2

```
 for subviews in self.profilescroll.subviews
    {
        if ((subviews is UITextField) && (subviews.tag == 0))
        {


            let btntext : UITextField = subviews as! UITextField
            btntext.resignFirstResponder()

        }

        if ((subviews is UITextField) && (subviews.tag == 1))
        {
            let btntext : UITextField = subviews as! UITextField
            btntext.resignFirstResponder()
        }
    }
```

this is where i put tag to the textfield.

```
 for i in 0 ..< 2
                    {
                        btnbudget = UITextField()
                        btnbudget.frame = CGRect(x: (CGFloat(i) * (((screenWidth - 160)/2) + 40)) + 40, y: 0, width: (screenWidth - 160)/2, height: 50)
                        btnbudget.font = UIFont(name: "Metropolis-SemiBold", size: 18)
                        btnbudget.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0
                        btnbudget.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
                        btnbudget.layer.borderColor = UIColor(hexString:"4B45A0").cgColor
                        btnbudget.tag = i
                        btnbudget.backgroundColor = UIColor(hexString: "#00000000")
                        btnbudget.text = budgetlist.object(at: i) as? String
                        btnbudget.textColor = UIColor(hexString:"4B45A0")
                        btnbudget.textAlignment = .center
                        btnbudget.delegate = self
                        budgetbtnview.addSubview(btnbudget)
}
```

where profilescroll is the view with 3 textfields in which i need to find textfield with tag values ranging from 0 to 1. but for some reason i am not getting the right one hence the keyboard is not returning.

Comment: Can you show the code where you set the tag for the textfields' ?

Comment: Are the text fields the immediate children of `profileScroll`? Is `profileScroll` a `UIScrollView` with a content view?

Comment: By default zero for every components. Did you set tag anywhere explicitly to your text field? where you are adding this budgetbtnview to scrollview

Comment: code edited yes i have explicitly set tags

Comment: You are discouraged from setting a zero tag explicitly because that's the default. Start with 10 or 100. And this is Swift: You can omit all parentheses around the `if` conditions: `if subviews is UITextField && subviews.tag == 0 { ...` is pretty valid syntax. And the plural form `subviews` for an actual **single** element is a bit confusing.

Comment: When you just want to dismiss the keyboard, why not simply use `self.view.endEditing(true)` ?

Comment: If using a Storyboard you could simply set an outlet to the text field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

given tag should be unique ...try this..

```
 for i in 100 ..< 102
{
btnbudget = UITextField()
btnbudget.frame = CGRect(x: (CGFloat(i) * (((screenWidth - 160)/2) + 40)) + 40, y: 0, width: (screenWidth - 160)/2, height: 50)
btnbudget.font = UIFont(name: "Metropolis-SemiBold", size: 18)
btnbudget.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0
btnbudget.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
btnbudget.layer.borderColor = UIColor(hexString:"4B45A0").cgColor
btnbudget.tag = i
btnbudget.backgroundColor = UIColor(hexString: "#00000000")
btnbudget.text = budgetlist.object(at: i) as? String
btnbudget.textColor = UIColor(hexString:"4B45A0")
btnbudget.textAlignment = .center
btnbudget.delegate = self
budgetbtnview.addSubview(btnbudget)
}
```

and ....

```
for subviews in self.profilescroll.subviews
{
if ((subviews is UITextField) && (subviews.tag == 100))
{


let btntext : UITextField = subviews as! UITextField
btntext.resignFirstResponder()

}

if ((subviews is UITextField) && (subviews.tag == 101))
{
let btntext : UITextField = subviews as! UITextField
btntext.resignFirstResponder()
}
}
```

but self.view.viewWithTag(101) approach is more appropriate than this

Answer (score 4):

You have assigned tag number to text field than don't need to loop over all subviews.

```
  textField.tag = 101
```

You can directly use tag number to get view like below...

```
if let txtField = self.view.viewWithTag(101) as? UITextField {
    print(txtField.text)

}
```

**Make sure all the tag you give to view should be unique otherwise you may get unwanted view.**

Comment: when i tried the same only textfield with tag 1 worked but not tag 0

Comment: @vishnu tag 0 is default for all the views, please use tags other than 0

Answer (score 1):

Let say you have three `UITextField` and you have set the `tags` as `0,1,2`

Now, you can simply loop through all the `Subview` of your `profilescroll`

```
for case let textField as UITextField in self.profilescroll.subviews {
    if textField.tag == 0 {
        // do something
        return
    }
    else if textfield.tag == 1 {
      // do something 
      return
    }
    else if textfield.tag == 2 {
    // do something 
    return
    }
}
```

This will also ignore cases where your `subview` is not an `UITextField` thereby saving time.